# Multiple Radio Buttons on One Line - Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I tried the code from the docs (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls) and found how to implement this:

[image]

Code below:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="form-group row">
      <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-2">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
            Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
            Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check disabled">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
            Option three is disabled
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Check me out
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

However, I would like to be able to have everything inline like this:

[image]

Is this possible? How?

---

Later Edit: Similar to the code in the example, I need to have some sort of a label with col-sm-2 and then have all the radio buttons inside a col-sm-10 container

---

Later Edit: I edited Abdeslem Charif's code a little and got exactly what I needed, thanks a lot. See code below:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Radio: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Option one</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Option Two</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Option tree</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Option four (disabled)</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: @MateuszJuruś, edited

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `radio-inline` class

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="form-group row">
      <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-2">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input radio-inline" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
            Option one</label>
            <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input radio-inline" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
            Option two</label>
            <label class="form-check-label disabled">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
            Option three</label>
        </div>
        
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Check me out
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Use the Inline style

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Option one</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Option Two</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Option tree</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Option four (disabled)</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I need the label also, please see the edited question

Comment: @AndreiRS I am glad it did helped you :)

Answer (score 4):

use the `.radio-inline` class if you want the radio buttons to appear on the same line

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also need the label, please see the edited question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with div class="row" and then using their grid system for columns

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** : How to display multiple radio fields inline

**Fix Detail** : Add all other radio fields with label in their own `div`, combine them in one parent `div` and then use css flex property on parent `div` [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```
.displayFlex { display: flex; }
```

**Notes** :

- In order to control radio field status we can set radio fields `name` property to same for all radio fields.
- But if we need status of all radio fields then we can addEventListeners on key change. And assign radio fields value as per requirment by overriding default `value` of `"on"`. [input type="radio"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)